# Laravel ManyToMany relation with singular table names

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to create ManyToMany relation between **samples** and **supposed_origins**.
In my firm, our convention is to have **singular table names**, so as mentioned in  https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#table-names, I defined :
*migrations*

```
  Schema::create('v3_sample', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('number_canonical', 6)->unique(); // business key
    $table->string('name')->nullable();
  };

  Schema::create('v3_supposed_origin', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('location_id')->unsigned(); // from other database
    $table->string('description');
  });

  Schema::create('v3_sample_supposed_origin', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');

    $table->integer('sample_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('sample_id')->references('id')->on('v3_sample')->onDelete('cascade');

    $table->integer('supposed_origin_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('supposed_origin_id')->references('id')->on('v3_supposed_origin')->onDelete('cascade');
  });
```

*models*

```
class Sample extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'v3_sample';

    public function supposed_origins() {
        dd($this);
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\SupposedOrigin');
    }
}

class SupposedOrigin extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'v3_supposed_origin';

    public function samples() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Sample');
    }   
}
```

and *controller*

```
class SampleController extends Controller
{
    // […]

    public function edit(Request $request, $number_canonical)
    {
        $sample_record = DB::table('v3_sample')->where('number_canonical', $number_canonical)->first();
        $supposed_origins = $sample_record->supposed_origins; 
        dd($supposed_origins); // returns ErrorException Undefined property: stdClass::$supposed_origins
```

and **SampleController** returns `ErrorException Undefined property: stdClass::$supposed_origins`

As I have singular table names, [the rule](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) that define to have pivot table with singular table names (sample_supposed_origin) to plural table names (samples and supposed_origins instead of my sample an supposed_origin) are not followed !

### Questions :

- Is singular naming the reason it can't find the relation?
- Is there a way to specify it correctly? Add pivot table model?

Additional informations : Laravel Framework 7.28.4, PHP 8.0.3, mariadb  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.47-MariaDB

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you are using the Query Builder, and not the Eloquent Query Builder.

`DB::table('v3_sample')->where('number_canonical', $number_canonical)->first()` will return an object representing the results from the database, but it is just a standard PHP Object.

You want:

`Sample::query()->where('number_canonical', $number_canonical)->first()`

This will return a `Sample` Model and you will have access to the relation you need.

In your case `$sample_record->supposed_origins`.

Answer (score 0):

As @KurtFriars mentionned in his answer, I change my controller to :

```
public function edit(Request $request, $number_canonical)
    {
        $sample_record = Sample::query()->where('number_canonical', $number_canonical)->first();
        $supposed_origins = $sample_record->supposed_origins;
```

and previous error disappears but I have an other error :

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table dbname.sample_supposed_origin' doesn't exist`
```

To have my *supposed_origins*, It requires also to improve my `Sample` model like this :

```
    public function supposed_origins() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            'App\SupposedOrigin',
            'v3_sample_supposed_origin',
            'sample_id',
            'supposed_origin_id'
        );
    }
```